# What is the error in this code?

Tags: html, sencha-touch, iphone

I am new to html5 web app programming. I found the following code for making a simple app:

```
<script class="hiddenSpellError"><!--mce:0--></script>

senchatouch/1.1.0/sencha-touch.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<link href="app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

but i am not getting the desired output. Pls help

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing external resources in the last two lines:

```
<link href="app.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Do you have files called "app.css" and "app.js" in the same directory as your html file?
Also, what is your desired output?

Comment: yes i am having those files. You can see the desired output on : http://miamicoder.com/2011/writing-a-sencha-touch-application-part-1/#comment-446

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant:

```
<link href="senchatouch/1.1.0/sencha-touch.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

for the second line.

Comment: i tried the same but i am not getting the output the same as shown on:
http://miamicoder.com/2011/writing-a-sencha-touch-application-part-1/#comment-446

Comment: Did you read the rest of the article and the rest of the series? Please do so first and then come back if you have more questions

Comment: Did you download the Sencha touch framework and included it as the article said: `In this file we need to include references to the Sencha Touch framework`

Comment: If you downloaded the framework from their site (http://www.sencha.com/learn/hello-world/)[http://www.sencha.com/learn/hello-world/], then the second line does not point to anywhere since the folder structure is different. And I don't see `sencha-touch.js` anywhere in your code

Comment: i just copied the code from the link i posted above and i am wondering what they have done!! also, i have saw many examples on other websites and compared to them, the code for index.html is too small and incomplete on the link which i have posted.so all i need the full code for the index.html file